# Search recursively all files with a given name replacing a word

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, find

From a given folder, I want to search recursively accross all subfolders searching for files with name `file.txt` replacing all occurences of `Foo` -case sensitive-
 with `Bar`.

Which is the simplest way of achieving this with basic scripting (Bash / sed / grep / find...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`find`** + **`sed`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "file.txt" -exec sed -i 's/Foo/Bar/g' {} \;
```